# Excessive CPU Usage caused by long running query?

Tags: sql-server, performance

We have been getting intermittent excess CPU usage at 100%. There is not a whole amount running on the system.
We also get warning of *Batch Requests/sec above threshold.: 1030*, which would seem to point to CPU issues.

The server has the below...

- 6 CPU cores
- 56 GB Memory

On the server this is what I see..

[image]

The queries running using *sys.dm_exec_requests* are below. Is this high CPU caused by that first query that is 14mins in cpu time? Why would it throttle all CPUs?

[image]

Comment: please have a look at your waits. the status of that query here is runnable, meaning it waits for something. either resources or info from some other table.

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: And no I/O as of the time of the post.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: 100% of cpu is used and only two queries are currently executing, the rest are runnable. This tells me that parallelism is most likely going on across your 6 cores, otherwise the runnable (other than an overloaded scheduler) should be running. Grab the plans for what's currently running and check them out. Grab the plan for the long running query as well (currently runnable) to see what it's doing. Post back with updates please.